# Remove space in cells that is creating a new paragraph within the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have few cells in my .csv file that has space between lines that is creating a new paragraph within the cell. So when I click on that cell only the first line of the cell is displayed in the formula bar.
I'm actually trying to read the .csv file on RStudio which is treating each line from the cell as a different row due to the unwanted spaces.

I have tried to use Wrap Text/Merge & Center but to no avail.

[image: Cell with space that is creating a new paragraph within the cell]

How do I remove space in cells that is creating a new paragraph within the cell?

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""),CHAR(13),"")
```

and if you want a space in there then use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "),CHAR(13)," ")
```

First formula:

[image]

and second formula:

[image]

Comment: Good answer. You can also use a free hex editor called [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) on the .csv file itself to confirm that those hex characters 0D (CHAR(10)) and 0A (CHAR(13)) are actually the characters causing the paragraph breaks.